# Java Eclipse Heat Index

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a complete beginner and hardly even know the basics of Java (I've only been in the class for two weeks). My first assignment is to calculate the heat index based on the current temperature and current humidity given by the user, in java using Eclipse. I have come up with a code, however, to no avail. My code does ask users to input the temperature and humidity, but it does not print out the results. I provided the UML diagram I was required to use to build the code that way you have a better understanding of why I did what I did. Ultimately, I think my problem lies somewhere in the process of passing values to and from different methods... Is there anyone who would be willing to take a look and possibly guide me in the right direction?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HeatIndexCalculator1 {

    private int temperature;
    private double humidity;
    private double heatIndex;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //Get current temp and humidity from user
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Please enter the current temperature in degrees Fahrenheit: ");
        int currentTemp = input.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("\nPlease enter the current humidity as a percentage: ");
        double currentHumidity = input.nextDouble();
    }

    private double calculateHeatIndex ( int currentTemp, double currentHumidity ) {
        //Setting parameters for Function
        int temperature = currentTemp;
        double humidity = currentHumidity;
        double answer;
        final double C1 = -42.379;
        final double C2 = 2.04901523;
        final double C3 = 10.14333127;
        final double C4 = -0.22475541;
        final double C5 = -.00683783;
        final double C6 = -5.481717E-2;
        final double C7 = 1.22874E-3;
        final double C8 = 8.5282E-4;
        final double C9 = -1.99E-6;
        int T = temperature;
        double R = humidity;
        double T2 = temperature * temperature;
        double R2 = humidity * humidity;

        //Function of Calculating Heat Index
        double answer = C1 + (C2 * T) + (C3 * R) + (C4 * T * R) + (C5 * T2) + (C6 * R2) + (C7 * T2 * R) + (C8 * T * R2) + (C9 * T2 * R2);

        return answer;
        }
    private void printHeatIndex( int currentTemp, double currentHumidity, double calculatedHeatIndex) { 
        double calculatedHeatIndex = answer;

        //Print Heat Index
        System.out.println("\nAt a temperature of" + currentTemp + "and a humidity of" + currentHumidity + "percent . . .\n");
        System.out.println("\nIt feels like:" + calculatedHeatIndex + "F");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you're not calling the other methods you've written from `main()`.

Comment: All I would need to add then is: calculateHeatIndex(); and  printHeatIndex();

Comment: Just add this line at end of `main` method: `printHeatIndex(currentTemp, currentHumidity, calculateHeatIndex(currentTemp, currentHumidity));` and add the `static` modifier to the `calculateHeatIndex` and `printHeatIndex` methods

Comment: now I am receiving an error that says Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 calculatedHeatIndex cannot be resolved to a variable

 at HeatIndexCalculator1.main(HeatIndexCalculator1.java:24)

Comment: Did you stick an extra "d" at the end of "calculate"?

Comment: I added: calculateHeatIndex(currentTemp, currentHumidity);
         printHeatIndex(currentTemp, currentHumidity, calculatedHeatIndex);

Comment: `calculateHeatIndex` is a function.  You will need to either assign the result to a variable, or use it somewhere else, but the way you wrote it, it will just throw it away.  The way you wrote the second statement, it expects `calculatedHeatIndex` to be a variable, not the result of the earlier function.  Try `double calculatedHeatIndex = calculateHeatIndex(...);` and then `printHeatIndex(currentTemp,currentHumidity,calculatedHeatIndex)`.

Comment: Hm.. the problem is with calculatedHeatIndex not calculateHeatIndex(). Also, I believe that creates multiple markers, but I'll try it.

Comment: What do you mean "multiple markers"?  (I'm asking so that if you have some sort of misconception, we might be able to explain what's really going on.)

Comment: Now it says I have the error: Duplicate local variable answer

 at HeatIndexCalculator1.calculateHeatIndex(HeatIndexCalculator1.java:48)
 at HeatIndexCalculator1.main(HeatIndexCalculator1.java:24)

Comment: I realized what you did, when you changed - ignore the multiple markers response (: 
However, how do I make return answer; become a varible. I thought having double calculatedHeatIndex = answer; would to the trick.

Comment: Inside `calculateHeatIndex` you have `double answer;` near the top, and `double answer = ...` near the bottom.  Both of these _declare_ a new variable because of the type name `double`.  So you ended up declaring two variables with the same name, which is no good.  Either remove the first `double answer;` or remove the word `double` from the second one.

Comment: Now it says answer cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: It was required to initialize heatIndex of type double in the class, but I never used it in the program. Would changing answer to heatIndex fix it?

Comment: I did that and it finally spit out a result! Now, I just need to calculated the result by hand and see if its correct, although it says the heat index is 0.0 and I dont think thats correct. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your main method as per below:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {

            //Get current temp and humidity from user
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.printf("Please enter the current temperature in degrees fahrenheit: ");
            int currentTemp = input.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("\nPlease enter the current humidity as a percentage: ");
            double currentHumidity = input.nextDouble();
//Creating object of HeatIndexCalculator class
            HeatIndexCalculator1 heatIndex = new HeatIndexCalculator1();
double x = heatIndex.calculateHeatIndex(..,..);
heatIndex.printHeatIndex(currentTemp,currentHumidity,x);
        }
```

Also, compiler may give your error because the methods in HeatIndexCalculator1 class are private, if you change them to public it works.